# Docker: Handling user uploads and saving files

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have been reading about `Docker`, and one of the first things that I read about docker was that `it runs images in a read-only manner`. This has raised this question in my mind, what happens if I need users to upload files? In that case where would the file go (are they appended to the image)? or in other words, how to handle uploaded files?

Comment: You can assign volumes (folders) on the host machine to map to folders on the docker container. That would likely be the way you want to keep certain files/folders around while allowing you to delete the container if you ever wanted to

Comment: Also, don't confuse an IMAGE with a CONTAINER. Images are read-only instructions of how to build a docker container

Comment: @JoePhillips: Amazing, if you could provide more details as an answer, it will be surely accepted.

Comment: I'm not really qualified to give details, to be honest. Someone else will hopefully provide a clear answer

Comment: @JoePhillips: Thank you very very much Joe. You've already been a lotta help :)

Answer (score 4):

Docker containers are meant to be immutable and replaceable - you should be able to stop a container and replace it with a newer version without any ill effects. It's bad practice to store any configuration or operational data inside the container.

The situation you describe with file uploads would typically be resolved with a `volume`, which mounts a folder from the host filesystem into the container. Any modifications performed by the container to the mounted folder would persist on the host filesystem. When the container is replaced, the folder is re-mounted when the new container is started.

It may be helpful to read up on volumes: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

docker containers use file systems similar to their underlying operating system, as it seems in your case Windows Nano Server(windows optimized to be used in a container). 
so any uploads to your container will be placed on the corresponding path you provided when uploading the file.

**but** this data is ephemeral, this means your data will persist until the container is for whatever reason stopped.
to use persistent storage you must provide a volume for your docker container, you can think of volumes as external disks attached to a container that mount on a path inside the container. this will persist data regardless of container state